# hi ... i'm stuck with passing data from an adapter recyclerview to a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my `RecyclerView` code:

```
class RecyclerAdapterMain(val product: ArrayList<ModelProductMain>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMain.ViewHolder>() {


    class ViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {


        val title: TextView = itemview.product_txt
        val price: TextView = itemview.price_product
        val imageproduct: ImageView = itemview.product_image

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val layoutview =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutview)


    }

    override fun getItemCount() = product.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val products = product[position]

        holder.title.text = products.title
        holder.price.text = products.price.toString()



        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {


            val activity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.homepage, ItemDetailsfragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()

            val bunde = Bundle()
            bunde.putString("title", products.title)
    

        }

    }

}
```

And this is my fragment that I want pass data to:

```
class ItemDetailsfragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_items_page, container, false)

        val title = Bundle()
        val get = title.getString("title")
        d("main", "$get")


        return view
    }
}
```

When I try to get data from Recyclerview adapter, I just get null parameter . I try so thing and also debugging my program and it says that the variable that come is null. I am stuck with this and i don't know what is wrong with this ...
can anyone hlep with this ...?

Comment: Did you set adapter to recycler view?

Comment: yes . body ... this is my code setting     val list = ArrayList<ModelProductMain>()



        for (i in 0..20) {

            list.add(ModelProductMain("title" , 12.000 , ""))

        }


        recycler_main.apply {

            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity , 2)
            adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(list)

        }

Answer (score 0):

While passing value to fragment :

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("title", products.title)

val myFragment = ItemDetailsfragment()
myFragment.arguments = bundle
        
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.homepage, myFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

While retrieving value :

```
val temp = arguments?.getString("title")
```